# How to symboilocate a crash report?

Tags: ios, symbolicate

Im wondering how to symbolicate a crash report generated from the release build of an iOS application. I have the .crash file that was sent to me by one of the Quality Assurance people. I also found the .dsym file corresponding to the archived application. So what do I do from here? I tried countless posts from all over google but nothing is working.

Comment: This will be closed as a duplicate to the MANY existing resources on the topic. To avoid that, post what you have actually tried and explain what is not working.

Comment: Well i tried out a bunch of sites and this is what they told me to do. One check if the uuids are the same as the build as in the crash report.  **uuid: 5a45fe3cc01a3b5d84e39a6f7af11e09 (armv7) 
uuid: 83fceda51a1b3dfc9a074275778c684c (armv7s)
uuid: a52b3cfd6b8e32f78e31d4b99ae4ec84 (arm64)**  So those are correct and when i take the uuid from the crash reports i get this id **a52b3cfd6b8e32f78e31d4b99ae4ec84**   So now i know that the crash report uuid is the same as the apps uuid

Comment: Just one more thing. Can xcode resymbolicate a crash report if the version of ios in xcode is less than the crash reports version? Im still using Xcode 5 and the highest os is 7.x , the crash reports are in 8.0. Could that be the issue?